# How to properly use assertion in python?

Tags: python, assert

I have a python program that needs to assert a lot of nested conditions before executing.

Python has a way to assert with `assert` statement,

Syntex: `assert condition, error_message(optional)`

but, I need to assert multiple nested conditions, and probably execute multiple statements in the assert.

What is proper way to use assert in python?

---

My thinking is: check `c` only when `b > a` is `true` and check `a > c` only both are true. And after assertion executes multiple statements like:- log the info and print the info etc..

Pseudocode:

```py
if c != null then
  if b > a then
    if a > c then
     print 'yippee!'
    else
     throw exception('a > c error')
  else
    throw exception('b > a error')
else
  throw exception('c is null')
```

Comment: Note that `assert` is only for basic sanity checking and debug purposes. It should *not* form an integral part of your business logic!

Comment: so how do I do sanity check my program. with normal IF ELSE?

Comment: For implementing vital business logic checks, yes, good old `if..else` or similar tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```py
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

assert b > a and c > b and a > c, 'Error: a is not greater than c'
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    assert b > a and c > b and a > c, 'Error: a is not greater than c'
AssertionError: Error: a is not greater than c
```

---

> something like this:- check c only when b > a is true and check a > c only both are true. And after assertion executes multiple statements like:- log the info and print the info etc..

You can use several `assert` statements one after another, like you'ld write several if statements under each other, except you've to take into account that your `assert`s can raise an exception, which you need to take care of. This way you can simply control the execution flow, and print/log whatever you need... For example something like this:

```py
def make_comperations(a, b, c = None): # note c is optional
  assert c is not None,  'Error: c is None'
  assert b > a, 'Error: a is not greater than b'
  assert c > a, 'Error: c is not greater than a'


try:
  make_comperations(1, 2, 3) # ok
  make_comperations(1, 2) # error
  make_comperations(1, 2, 0) # error, but won't be executed since the line above will throw an exception
  print("All good!")
except AssertionError as err:
  if str(err) == 'Error: c is None':
    print("Log: c is not given!")
  if str(err) == 'Error: a is not greater than b':
    print("Log: b > a error!")
  elif str(err) == 'Error: c is not greater than a':
    print("Log: c > a error!")
```

Output:

```
Log: c is not given!
```

Comment: something like this:- check c only when `b > a` is true and check `a > c` only both are true. And after assertion executes multiple statements like:- log the info and print the info etc..